# Flutter : Android emulator Out of memory

Tags: flutter, android-emulator, out-of-memory

In my flutter application After a few hot reload my application is terminated and I got `Out of memory` error, I am using android emulator:

```
E/Dart    ( 8136): ../../third_party/dart/runtime/vm/zone.cc: 94: error: Out of memory.
E/DartVM  ( 8136): version=2.12.3 (stable) (Wed Apr 14 11:02:39 2021 +0200) on "android_ia32"
E/DartVM  ( 8136): pid=8136, thread=8228, isolate_group=main(0x9e8b6100), isolate=main(0x7e257c00)
E/DartVM  ( 8136): isolate_instructions=7c179300, vm_instructions=7c179300
```

To fix this I added `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096M` in gradle.properties and

```
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "6G"
}
```

inside build.gradle file but I also have this problem.

This is doctor:

$ flutter doctor

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.6, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio
[✓] VS Code (version 1.56.2)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!
```

I still executed flutter clean in the terminal but I have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced this problem.

Adding more Internal Storage to the emulator fixed my problem.

Comment: I added too but I also have problem.